# docker (windows10 wsl2) unable to mount ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i try to map ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d, the following are the commands in the yml

```
volumes:
  - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  #- ./nginx/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  #- ./nginx/conf.d/docker1.example.com.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/docker1.example.com.conf      
  #- ./nginx/conf.d/docker2.example.com.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/docker2.example.com.conf      
  - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
  - ./src:/var/www
```

In the image, under /etc/nginx/conf.d, there is a default.conf exists, when i run docker-compose up, it try to make a directory named default.conf, so the nginx starts with error

I also tried to create ./nginx/conf.d/default.conf first before running the command in local directory, but still not work.

Anyone know how to map ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d in correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are doing it the right way, except for a small, annoying bit:

When mapping the content between the two locations, you should make sure the sintax is correct `/:/` when separating the two.

```
volumes:
  - ./nginx/nginx.conf/:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  - ./nginx/conf.d/default.conf/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  - ./nginx/conf.d/docker1.example.com.conf/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/docker1.example.com.conf      
  - ./nginx/conf.d/docker2.example.com.conf/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/docker2.example.com.conf      
  - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
  - ./src/:/var/www
```

Comment: - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d not working error: ERROR: for 901c2e0a876a_test_nginx  Cannot create container for service nginx: mkdir /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-bind-mounts/Ubuntu-20.04/de3ff82f9842d3f2459da6cc70ecac8114d2ddab50680fb2ea54cfeac3c6be7b: mkdir /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-bind-mounts/Ubuntu-20.04/de3ff82f9842d3f2459da6cc70ecac8114d2ddab50680fb2ea54cfeac3c6be7b: not a directory

Comment: those lines i commented out is work but i don't want to mount every single file one by one, otherwise i need to restart every time when i add a additional file

Comment: That's good news as it means it's now mapping properly. Looking better to what you are mapping through, I noticed you actually don't need the second, third and fourth ones as you are anyway mapping the whole directory with `./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d`, so you're right, those can be left commented out (or removed directly)

Comment: This way you will have a volume mapping the entire directory of nginx config files, removing the need to restart the containers every time you have to add / remove any

Comment: ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d not working, it must cause error

Comment: Try renaming your folder from conf.d to conf, it might be looking at it as a file with that dot

Comment: it works, nows here is the command - ./nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d

Comment: Glad that helped - Careful anyway with the `/:/`, as there are cases where that causes error if not separated correctly.. I can vouch for it as it caused me days of pain!